Apps without migrations must not have relations to apps with migrations. Why?
There is a vague paragraph in django docs:

Apps without migrations must not have relations (ForeignKey,
ManyToManyField, etc.) to apps with migrations. Sometimes it may work,
but it’s not supported.

I have 5 years of experience and never encountered problems in these cases. In what case it's dangerous to have relation to "apps with migrations" ?

Do you understand what the documentation means by "relations" over there? If you do you'll probably understand why it says so. Or is it that you misunderstand what the documentation means by "apps without migrations"? Can you please clarify your understanding so we can better answer your question.

Thank you. it is resolved by Golfbauer. the doc should have said unmanaged apps and models instead of "without migration"

I see, I did think that might be your confusion just wanted to confirm before posting any answer. It seems though that Golfbauer's answer resolves that confusion of yours so I'll refrain from posting another answer :)

The warning in the documentation about having multiple apps with some not managed through djangos migration system is rooted in the potential issues with schema management and consistency.
Imagine we have 2 apps:

Without migrations: This app manages its models through manual schemas or legacy methods.
With migrations: This app is managed and tracked by django through migrations applied to the db

Any schema changes in either app will not be properly reflected in the other, causing the schemas to go out of sync eventually. You also lack proper dependency management, which might cause migrations to run in the wrong order.
In general, it's not advisable to manage multiple apps in different ways. Eventually, this will lead to issues.
I wrote this based on my understanding of django and migrations. Don't take this as fact.I just did not like the first comment you received.

Thank you. The doc should have said unmanaged apps instead of "without migration" as I first thought it means a new app without migrations!

No worries. Yeah the wording is a bit weird. Also took me a bit to understand what the author meant.
